# Could not load properties

Tags: java, xml, spring, web-services

hi i am going to develop web-services in java (NetBeans) but have problems with get conection, i get the following error:

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: C
    Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: C
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(FtpClient.java:957)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(FtpClient.java:917)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1012)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:998)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:294)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:393)
        at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:103)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:179)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:158)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(Proper    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:68)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:76)
        at com.rsa.ims.components.spring.SimpleApplicationLoader.loadBeanFactory(SimpleApplicationLoader.java:134)
        at com.rsa.ims.components.spring.SimpleApplicationLoader.useBeanFactory(SimpleApplicationLoader.java:105)
        at com.rsa.command.ConnectionFactory.getSpringBeanTarget(ConnectionFactory.java:183)
        at com.rsa.command.ConnectionFactory.getTarget(ConnectionFactory.java:156)
        at com.rsa.command.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
        at com.rsa.command.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:281)
        at com.arame.rsa.cmdConnection.getConnection(cmdConnection.java:33)
        at com.arame.rsa.ApiRsaTest.main(ApiRsaTest.java:49)
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.arame.rsa.cmdConnection.closeConnection(cmdConnection.java:59)
        at com.arame.rsa.ApiRsaTest.main(ApiRsaTest.java:94)
```

I have the config.properties where is the URL and Context.xml this file processing to retrieve properties from a file config.properties also have log4j.xml/dtd all them in my classpath.

this is my con Context.xml

```
<beans default-lazy-init="true" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">

    <bean name="PrimaryPropertyPlaceHolderPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

        <property name="order" value="10"/>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
        <property name="location" value="file://C:\\Users\\gerardo.granados\\Documents\\APITest\\build\\classes\\config.properties"/>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false"/>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="ConnectionInfoProvider"
          class="com.rsa.command.PropertiesConnectionInfoProvider"
          lazy-init="false">
        <property name="propertiesFile" value="config.properties"/>
    </bean>


    <alias alias="CommandAPIConnection" name="SOAPCommandTargetBasicAuth"/>


    <bean name="ClusterTarget" lazy-init="true"
          class="com.rsa.command.RemoteCommandTargetFactoryBean">
        <property name="providerURL" value="t3s://node1-address,node2-address:7002"/>
        <property name="connectionInfoProvider" ref="ConnectionInfoProvider"/>
        <property name="targetClass" value="com.rsa.command.EJBRemoteTarget"/>
        <property name="cacheable" value="true"/>
    </bean>


    <bean name="SpecificNodeTarget" lazy-init="true"
          class="com.rsa.command.RemoteCommandTargetFactoryBean">
        <property name="providerURL" value="t3s://node2-address:7002"/>
        <property name="connectionInfoProvider" ref="ConnectionInfoProvider"/>
        <property name="targetClass" value="com.rsa.command.EJBRemoteTarget"/>
        <property name="cacheable" value="true"/>
        <property name="properties">
            <props>

                <prop key="com.rsa.naming.pin.to.primary.server">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Any suggestion???? Thanks

Comment: At some point in your config, you're trying to make a connection to a machine you've identified as `C` as evidenced by-->`java.net.UnknownHostException: C`

Answer (score 3):

In the line:

```
<property name="location" value="file://C:\\Users\\gerardo.granados\\Documents\\APITest\\build\\classes\\config.properties"/>
```

Remove the first two slashes after `file:`. Like this:

```
<property name="location" value="file:C:\\Users\\gerardo.granados\\Documents\\APITest\\build\\classes\\config.properties"/>
```

This worked for me in a related issue.